# Who is 'self' in a Ruby class level block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, this is pretty clear in Javascript who self would be in this situation, but I'm not positive in Ruby.

```
class Product

  after_initialize do |p|
    p.set_approved
  end

  set_approved
    approved = true
  end
end
```

Because I was pretty sure p would be since I'm sure the code is some sort of

```
def after_initialize(&blk)
  yield(self)
end
```

And the context of both methods is `self`, why do I have to do

```
def set_approved(p)
  p.approved = true
end
```

Comment: In Ruby `self` almost always refers to the object instance or class context the method is defined in. Where does `a_i` exist? Is that your short-form for `after_initialize`? Try not to do that in questions.

Comment: @sawa `self` can (usually) be implied in Ruby when calling methods. So in this case approved is a db column and automagically created by Rails.

Comment: I missed the one you have in `yield(self)`.

Comment: Specifically in Rails's callback methods such as `after_initialize`, `self` is the object and not the class.  See the examples in the ActiveRecord::Callbacks doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby `self` is much more locked down and predictable than `this` is in JavaScript. You really have to go out of your way to switch the binding of a block, and when you do you can surprise people, which leads to confusion, so it's usually avoided.

Here's what's actually happening and how you can side-step it if it's undesirable:

```
class Product
  # Usage type #1: Supply a Proc
  after_initialize do |p|
    # self here refers to the Product class since this block was defined at the
    # class level.
    p.set_approved
  end

  # Usage type #2: Call a method
  after_initialize :trigger_set_approved

protected
  def trigger_set_approved
    # This is an instance method, so self is an instance of Product
    self.set_approved
  end
end
```

Rebinding the block given to `after_initialize` could have detrimental effects so it's not usually done. If you wanted to call a class method in there defined on Product you'd have to call `self.class.class_method_name` instead of just `class_method_name`.

In other words, it's expected that the execution context of the block is not switched under ordinary circumstances.

Comment: Yeah, so `after_initialize` is a class_method, so why doesn't `self` in `set_approved` refer to the instance `p` from which it was called. And any idea how they got `product` to be `self` for the instance that was just initialized, rather than the class it was created in?

Comment: If you have `set_approved` defined as an instance method there's no need for the `p` argument, it will be `self`.